# attempt to index upvalue 'player' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, roblox

please help me! I am making a game but i keep running into the same problem

i tried many things but nothing worked

```
script.Parent.Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    print("yeet")
    player.leaderstats.PuzzlePieces.Value =  player.leaderstats.PuzzlePieces.Value + 1
end)
```

Comment: `Player` or `player`?  Why are you using `player` as upvalue?  Shouldn't it be global variable?

Comment: can you right the script down? i don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error : *attempt to index upvalue 'player' (a nil value)* means that you are trying to use a variable that has not been defined. In this case "player". So you just need to create the player variable by pointing it at the right object in `game.Players`

I'm assuming that you've got this Script inside a player's model

The player model and humanoid live in `game.Workspace` the leaderstats object lives in an object in `game.Players`. You need the two to talk to each other.

```
local playerModel = script.Parent
playerModel.Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()

    -- use the player's name to find the player object in game.Players
    local playerName = playerModel.Name
    local player = game.Players[playerName]

    -- update the leaderboard
    player.leaderstats.PuzzlePieces.Value =  player.leaderstats.PuzzlePieces.Value + 1
end)
```

Hope this helps