# attempt to index field 'LocalPlayer' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, roblox

i have been trying to fix this problem in my game:
"attempt to index field 'LocalPlayer' (a nil value)"

but nothing i tried to do worked
here is the code:

please do not mind the extremely un-efficient lines of code

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

script.Parent.Humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    print("yeet")
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.PuzzlePieces.Value = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.PuzzlePieces.Value + 1
end)
```

and this is the error message i get:

```
attempt to index field 'LocalPlayer' (a nil value)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [attempt to index upvalue 'player' (a nil value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286539/attempt-to-index-upvalue-player-a-nil-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalPlayer can only be used in localscripts, and if you are changing leaderstats, you would need to use remotefunctions if your using the localplayer way, or you could use a script and then detect is a player dies and give them a leaderstat value.

PS. If your into roblox I very well recommand https://scriptinghelpers.org/, it is a great roblox scripting Q&A.