# How do you create a light inside the player?

Tags: roblox

Im trying to create a light when the player spawns in but im running into multiple problems

I've tried many formats and functions always keep getting either

"Attempt to index nil value"

"[head(and other things)] is not a member of [humanoid(and other things)]"

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(playersdude)
    playersdude.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        local humanoid = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
        local light = Instance.new("PointLight")
        light.Parent = game.Players.LocalPlayer.HumanoidRootPart
    end)
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into the same problem as this guy : ([attempt to index field 'LocalPlayer' (a nil value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289849/attempt-to-index-field-localplayer-a-nil-value))

I'm assuming that you've written this in a Script somewhere. `LocalPlayer`can only be accessed in a LocalScript. Trying to access it from a server Script will result in LocalPlayer being nil. Luckily, you don't need to use LocalPlayer at all!

You can use the `char` provided in the CharacterAdded connection to find the player's head.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(playersdude)
    playersdude.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        -- search through the character model to find the head
        local head = char:FindFirstChild("Head", true)

        -- add a light bright enough to make them glow like the mid-morning sun
        local light = Instance.new("PointLight", head)
        light.Brightness = 100
    end)
end)
```