# Attempt to index nil with 'FindFirstChild' (Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

In the Roblox Studio Error **attempt to index nil with 'FindFirstChild'**. A ServerScript was used (LocalScript also not work)

Please help, thanks.

I am creating a script that, when touched by a player, changes the player's personal variable.

My script:

```
local player = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer
local StagePlayer = player:FindFirstChild('StagePlayer').Value

function onTouched(stage2)
    if stage2.Parent:FindFirstChild('Humanoid') then
        if StagePlayer < 2 then
            StagePlayer += 1
            StagePlayer.Value += 1
        end
    end
end

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(onTouched)
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: You're running into the [same problem as this person.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289849/attempt-to-index-field-localplayer-a-nil-value) see if their answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening (I guess) is because when the script is executing
'FindFirstChild' is returning nil or the StagePlayer doesn't exist in the 'LocalPlayer' object. Maybe you should change the 'Local Player' into -

```
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character
local StagePlayer = character:FindFirstChild('StagePlayer')
```

or you should check if StagePlayer exists by running your game and searching for it in the browser.